# Axis 1.2.1 Tomcat server-config.wsdd logging problem

Tags: tomcat, axis

I want to log the soap request and response that comes to/from my server(Tomcat). I looked for info on the internet, and I have declared the log handler as said in all the pages I found with google:
    
          
     
And then invoke the handler in the corresponding flow.

The problem is... that it does nothing. Have anyone run into a problem similar to that one?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Related with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638631/how-can-i-log-with-log4j-soap-request-and-response-in-axis-1-x