# How can I log with Log4J SOAP request and response in AXIS 1.x?

Tags: soap, log4j, axis

I am having the next problem:

I want to log the SOAP requests/responses that land on my web service (server side). Trying to configure my web service in the wsdd file. I am always landing on pages like the next one:

[How to use the org.apache.axis.handlers.LogHandler](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=35765)

Which recommends to configure the Apeche Axis LogHandler to log the request/response. That is not valid for me, since a)there is no way to link the log4j there, and b)I just am not able to make it work.

Does anyone know a way to make my log4j to log the request/responses?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

So after hours or Googling out there in the web, I decided to get adventurous and program my own handler. Is much easier than expected.

I made a class that extends the abstract class BasicHandler (org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler), and implements the invoke method loging the request or the response. Here is my class, which I have baptized as SOAPLogHandler :

```
package com.mypackage.axishandlers;

import org.apache.axis.AxisFault;
import org.apache.axis.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class SOAPLogHandler extends BasicHandler {

private static Logger LOG= Logger.getLogger(SOAPLogHandler.class);
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public void invoke(MessageContext msgContext) throws AxisFault {
    if(msgContext.getResponseMessage() != null && msgContext.getResponseMessage().getSOAPPart() != null) {
        LOG.info(" Response = " + msgContext.getResponseMessage().getSOAPPartAsString());
    } else {
        if(msgContext.getRequestMessage() != null && msgContext.getRequestMessage().getSOAPPartAsString() != null) {
            LOG.info(" Request = " + msgContext.getRequestMessage().getSOAPPartAsString());
        }    
    }
}  }
```

The idea is, to log first the request, and when processed, log the response. So, in the **server-config.wsdd** (or the wsdd file from your client if you are in the client side), we have to add a handler pointing to that class, and configure it to uses in the request/response chain:

1st add the handler

```
 <handler name="log" type="java:com.mypackage.axishandlers.SOAPLogHandler"/>
```

2nd add the use of that handler to the request/response from the http transport (focus on the log handler)

```
 <transport name="http">
  <requestFlow>
   <handler type="log"/>
   <handler type="URLMapper"/>
   <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.HTTPAuthHandler"/>
  </requestFlow>
  <responseFlow>
   <handler type="log"/>
  </responseFlow>
...
 </transport>
```

With that, the magic should be done, and you should receive a pretty log from the request/responses!

Disclaimer: I am not really sure from what will happend if you use some kind of SOAP multipart thing.

Comment: I found your post very helpful. I am struggling in getting response XML. I am able to get the request but response SOAP is not getting, infact invoke method is invoking only at request phase.I have did all configuration suggested. Also, when I add entries in Global configuration for request and response then only I am getting both request and response but inside transport tag, I am getting only request and no response.

Comment: I am using TestNG and Selenium. Where should I add the handler? In pom.xml or TestNG.xml ?

Comment: I found this answer very useful but with this I am not able to log soapfault(exception). Please suggest a way to do the same.I have  faultFlow tag but it is not working

Comment: I have not found anything similar to msgContext.getResponseMessage() for fault messages(like msgContext.getFaultMessage), so there is nothing incorrect with the handler itself I suppose. I have the feeling like something is catching your request before reaching this handler when getting a soap fault.I am sorry I cant help more right now, maybe you can check your server-config.wsdd

Answer (score 19):

Save this file as "client-config.wsdd" in the working directory as you do for log4j.properties .

If you don't want to alter any code and debug your axis web service client, you can follow this method to log all incoming and outgoing soap messages.

```
<deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/"
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">

<handler name="log" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.LogHandler" >
    <parameter name="LogHandler.fileName" value="c:/logs/axis.log"/>
</handler>

<globalConfiguration>
    <requestFlow>
        <handler type="log" />
    </requestFlow>
    <responseFlow>
        <handler type="log" />
    </responseFlow>
</globalConfiguration>

<transport name="http"
    pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender" />

</deployment>
```

Comment: Came across this issue when troubleshooting a ColdFusion 11 installation that was calling .NET WebServices, and kept getting "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused". This helped me track it to a wrong default namespace in the SOAP envelope. (it uses "mx.webservices").

Answer (score 12):

You need to add an Axis logger in your `log4.xml` configuration file, like below:

```
<logger name="org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender">
   <level value="DEBUG"/>
   <appender-ref ref="someLogAppender"/>
</logger>
```

`someLogAppender` may be an existing Log4J appender, or you may want to define a dedicated one, like below:

```
<appender name="someLogAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
   <param name="File" value="/my/path/to/axis.log" />
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n" />
   </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Spring boot: Just add `logging.level.org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender = DEBUG` in the application.properties file

Answer (score 6):

I know its a old thread, but may be useful for people looking for answers.

For AXIS-1 Server side logging, update your `server-config.wsdd` like below. `server-config.wsdd` is under `WEB-INF` folder of your war file.

A new handler for log. The file name along with path is configurable.

```
<handler name="log" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.LogHandler">
  <parameter name="LogHandler.fileName" value="/tmp/req-res-axis.log" />
</handler>
```

You can also use the `LogHandler.writeToConsole` parameter with the value as `"true"` to log in your console log.

Then update the `<globalConfiguration>` section to have

```
<requestFlow>
 <handler type="log"/>         
</requestFlow>
<responseFlow> 
 <handler type="log"/>
</responseFlow>
```

If the `requestFlow` and `responseFlow` contains other handlers ,put the log as the first handler.

This should be only used for debugging purpose not for production. Since the logging is naive and do the normal write operation on the file without any buffer. Secondly, the log file will grow to GB's since there is no rollover mechanism.

For AXIS-1 Client Side logging, update your `client-config.wsdd` like below. The `client-config.wsdd` should go into your `classpath` directly under a root folder configured in the `classpath` not in any sub-folders.  The best location is the same directory where your `log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties` file is present(Thanks to #MukeshKoshyM post above).

```
    <deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">

    <handler name="log" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.LogHandler" >
     <parameter name="LogHandler.fileName" value="/tmp/axis_req_res.log"/>
    </handler>

    <globalConfiguration>
      <requestFlow>
        <handler type="log" />
     </requestFlow>
     <responseFlow>
        <handler type="log" />
     </responseFlow>
    </globalConfiguration>

<transport name="http"
    pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender" />
</deployment>
```

The same issue mentioned for server side logging is applicable for client side as well.

For production, write your own log handler by extending `org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler` and configure the class file in the handler. Please look the above answer from #raspayu to configure your own. To log the faults override the `public void onFault(MessageContext msgContext)` method in your Handler.

Answer (score 3):

A solution to log the Axis Faults is extend the OnFault method  :

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.apache.axis.AxisFault;
import org.apache.axis.MessageContext;
import org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler;

public class SOAPLogHandler extends BasicHandler {

  private static final String AXIS = "AXIS";
  private static final String AXIS_FAULT = "AXIS FAULT";
  private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SOAPLogHandler.class);
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

  @Override
  public void invoke(MessageContext msgContext) throws AxisFault {
    logMessage(AXIS, msgContext);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFault(MessageContext msgContext) {
    try {            
        logMessage(AXIS_FAULT,msgContext);
    } catch (AxisFault axisFault) {
        LOG.error("Error on logging messages ",axisFault);
    }
  }

  private void logMessage(String preamble, MessageContext msgContext) throws AxisFault {
    if (msgContext.getResponseMessage() != null && msgContext.getResponseMessage().getSOAPPart() != null) {
        LOG.info("{} Response ={}",preamble ,msgContext.getResponseMessage().getSOAPPartAsString());
        return;
    }

    if (msgContext.getRequestMessage() != null && msgContext.getRequestMessage().getSOAPPartAsString() != null) {
        LOG.info("{} Request={}",preamble,msgContext.getRequestMessage().getSOAPPartAsString());
    }
  }
}
```

It is also mandatory to set the handler in the global configuration request flow, in the wsdd file will be something like this :

```
<globalConfiguration>     
  <requestFlow>
    <handler type="log" />
  </requestFlow>
  <responseFlow>
    <handler type="log" />
  </responseFlow>
</globalConfiguration>

<handler name="log" type="java:your.package.SOAPLogHandler"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Axis by default is checking for file client-config.wsdd. We need to keep this file in the location same as log4j.xml or log4j.properties. Log file will be generated at the location specified on log handeller. Ensure the folder structure exists.

`mukesh`

Comment: Didn't knew about that default behaviour. Thanks for the info!